# Barplot: NA vs empty strings

Tags: r, string, bar-chart, na

I'm using a barplot (and table) to show string data distribution. I have both NA and empty strings, however, in the barplot they are not differentiable. See for example:

```
a <- c('a','a','b',NA,'')
barplot(table(a,useNA='always'))
```

Any idea on how I can automatically add a 'NA' label to differentiate NA from empty strings?

Comment: Change NA to string? `a[is.na(a)]<-"NA"; barplot(table(a))`

Comment: Sounds good, but I need to change it before each barplot if I don't want to affect the original data. I will use this if there is no better way of doing. Thanks.

Comment: If it helps, I think NAs are always plotted last.

Comment: You could only change the labels in the chart using the argument `names.arg` instead of changing it everywhere in the data.

Comment: In fact it doesn't work in my case since 'a' is a factor in my case

Answer (score 5):

That should do the trick:

```
d <- factor(c("a", "a", "b", NA, ""))
barplot(table(d, useNA = "always"), names.arg = c(levels(d), "NA"))
```

As highlighted by [ilir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3533599/ilir), `names.arg`can be used to change the labels in the barplot. As the `NA` category seems to eb the last one (as mentioned by [zx8754](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680068/zx8754)) you can just add the string representation to the levels and you have the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

In fact if I don't change NA to 'NA' is all the data set, factor is no more an issue. I added a check since there may be no NA within the dataset:

```
a <- c('a','a','b',NA,'')
b <- table(a,useNA='always')
my.names <- names(b)
my.names[is.na(my.names)] <- 'NA'
barplot(b,names.arg=my.names)
```

I guess there is a more simple way to write that, but it works.